# how would we print out the three digit numbers in a string using regex in c++?

Tags: regex, string

Example input

```
abc55def789KK23GOOD9999910ONEM109ORE19k6
```

Output

```
789 109
```

Example input

```
abcdef
```

Output

```
-1
```

This is what I need to achieve via the regex code.

I have gone through numerous websites for tutorials but couldn't decipher it as needed.

My idea was to use this regex

```
rx("[0-9][0-9][0-9]""\\-""[0-5][0-5]")
```

But then I couldn't understand the `smatch` flag and how to retrieve the results.

Comment: Try `rx(R"((?:^|\D)(\d{3})(?!\d))")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [sample C++ demo](https://ideone.com/55viyg) showing how to extract 3 digit chunks not enclosed with other digits:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"((?:^|\D)(\d{3})(?!\d))");
    std::string s = "abc55def789KK23GOOD9999910ONEM109ORE19k6"; // "abcsd"; => Not Found
    if (regex_search(s, r)) {
        for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                                 i != std::sregex_iterator();
                                 ++i)
        {
            std::smatch m = *i;
            std::cout << m[1].str() << '\n';
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nyaWaj/1). The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|\D)` -  a start of a string or any non-digit (the `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that consumes the text matched with its pattern - we have to use it since C++ `std::regex` does not support lookbehinds - and thus the following caprturing group (`(\d{3})`) will have an ID of `1`, not `2`)
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: any 3 digits
- `(?!\d)` - the 3 digits captured should not be followed with a digit (this `(?!...)` is a *negative lookahead* that checks if a pattern matches immediately to the right of the current location without putting the matched text into the match).

The `m[1].str()` is used to access the value captured into Group 1.